# Can we always find homotopy of two paths which lies "between" the paths?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $\gamma_0,\gamma_1:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be paths such that $\gamma_0(0)=\gamma_1(0)$ and $\gamma_0(1)=\gamma_1(1)$.  I wish to show that there is a homotopy $\Gamma:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ from $\gamma_0$ to $\gamma_1$ that satisfies the following:

- For all $(s,t)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]$, $\Gamma(s,t)$ is not in the unbounded face of $\gamma_0([0,1])\cup\gamma_1([0,1])$.

PS: If the answer is no, are there additional restrictions which we could place on $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ which would allow this?  (Ex. rectifiable, differentiable, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

If you allow the contour of the union of those two paths to form a simple closed curve*, this is true, and can be seen as a consequence of the [Schoenflies Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem) together with the fact that the disk is contractible.

---

*I think this is the case, since you are talking about "unbounded face".

Comment: I am a little concerned about this.  Just because the bounded face is homeomorphic to the the disk, does this tell us that that homeomorphism extends to a homeomorphism from the boundary to the circle?  I think you are using something like this.

Comment: @TrevorRichards Search up for "Jordan-Brouwer Separation Theorem". It can be found on Bredon, for example (page 234). It states precisely that the embedded $S^1$ (the image of the closed curve) is the boundary of each component, in particular of the bounded face.

Comment: I just read the Jordan Brouwer Separation Theorem, and I am sorry to be dense, but it still does not seem obvious.  Just because the embedded $S^1$ is the boundary of each component, it is still not at all clear that a homeomorphism of the bounded component extends to a homeomorphism on the closure of the bounded component.  Am I just missing something?

Comment: @TrevorRichard Don't worry : ). I take it you mean that by "bounded component" you are not including the boundary, correct? However, the Schoenflies Theorem entails that the *closure* of the bounded component is homeomorphic to $D^2$ (the closed disk). Bredon also mentions the theorem, and you can see it in his book.

Comment: I see, thank you, I will take a look at Bredon when I get the chance.  Thanks very much.